# Laravel query builder orderBy id not ordering correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently joining 2 tables together like this:

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
->leftjoin('stripe_transactions','transactions.transaction_id','=','stripe_transactions.id')
->orderBy('transactions.id', 'desc')
->get();
```

My output is not being ordered by the transaction table id though. It's being ordered by the stripe_transactions.id instead.

I've tried reading the docs and creating multiple queries but same results.

Looking for something like this: (This doesn't work due to the `where`)

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions','transactions.id', 'transactions.transaction_id')
->join('stripe_transactions','stripe_transactions.id')
->where('transactions.transaction_id','=','stripe_transactions.id')
->orderBy('transactions.id', 'desc')
->get();
```

When I run that query I get the error:

> Unknown column '' in 'on clause'

To clear things up I should mention in my table `transactions` there is a column called `id` and a column called `transaction_id`. I want to Order my table by the `id` in the transaction table.

Comment: `::table()` should only have 1 argument. If you want specific columns, add a `->select("column, another")`, and your join syntax is wrong... It's `->join("table", "column", "condition", "other_column")`. Check you syntax against the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: ->join('stripe_transactions','transactions.id','=','stripe_transactions.id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the `join` and `where` clause in your query. Try the query below:

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
->join('stripe_transactions','transactions.transaction_id','=','stripe_transactions.id')
->select('transactions.id', 'transactions.transaction_id')
->orderBy('transactions.id', 'desc')
->get();
```